# For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to know if this is a valid application of the Enumeration Principle. Thanks in advance.

---

Claim: For any natural number $n$, $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable.

Proof. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the set $\mathcal{L} = \left\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -, /, * \right\}$. For any $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb{Q}^n$, each $x_i$ can be labelled by elements of $\mathcal{L}$ and therefore each $x$ can be labelled by elements of $\mathcal{L}$. For example, we can label $(\frac{1}{2}, -30, 4)$ by the sequence $(1, /, 2, *, -, 3, 0, *, 4)$, where the asterisk is used to separate components. Hence, $\mathbb{Q}^n$ can be labelled by a countable set. By the Enumeration Principle, $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable.

---

For anyone who's interested:

- A set $A$ can be *labelled* by a set $B$ if there is an injection from $A$ to the set of finite sequences of elements of $B$. That is, each element of $A$ can be assigned a unique finite sequence of elements of $B$.
- The Enumeration Principle: Any set that can be labelled by a countable set is countable.

Comment: This is a correct proof - and new to me. The standard argument would use the previously proved theorem that the product of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: Funny, I've [written about this proof technique](https://blog.math.coffee/post/20181115/countable-sets/) but I've never heard it called the 'enumeration principle' before. What book(s) use that terminology? In any case, your argument is correct.

Comment: "each xi can be labelled by elements of L"  this should be "each $x_i$ can be labelled by elements of $L\setminus \{*\}$".  You need to specifically reserve $*$ as a deliminator between rationals only.  I don't see much wrong with your proof.

Comment: So... a corollary or pre-lemma seems to be that given any finite set we can find a surjection from the finite strings of the finite elements to any countable set.  Interesting.

Comment: We take it for granted that we can map express every integer as a finite combination of the finite set  $\{0,1,....,9,-\}$.  (Which is reasonably; that's just the decimal system) but maybe we need to prove it first: That for any finite set $A$ with at least two elements that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A^n$ is countably infinite.... or is that what you call "the enumeration principal".

Comment: By the way, your (nice) proof is cleaner if, instead of introducing "*" as a symbol to separate entries, you just use "," itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but there is a more straightforward application of the enumeration principle, assuming you already know that $\Bbb Q$ itself is countable: simply label each element $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ by itself! This is an injection from $\Bbb Q^n$ to the set of finite sequences of elements of $\Bbb Q$; since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, the enumeration principle shows that $\Bbb Q^n$ is countable.

This observation is an illustration of an important strategy for doing mathematics: whenever possible, use facts that have already been established and add a small amount of reasoning to deduce the next fact—this will be better than going back to first principles for each argument. Here, the encoding of rational numbers by finite strings already went into the proof that $\Bbb Q$ is countable, and it's nice to observe that we don't have to do that encoding step again here.